# Is it possible to have a local authoritative DNS that falls back to Route 53 for unknown local subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have a local Forward Lookup Zone (Win Server 2003) for zxurian.com that has it's own A record, as well as a few subdomain records. I also use Route 53 for public DNS, and have a hosted zone there of "zxurian.com"

Is it possible to setup my local DNS to be first in the chain for computers behind it, but if a request for a subdomain isn't found locally, pass it to Route 53 for further lookup? I'd rather not copy every subdomain from Route 53 into my local DNS.

Ex. request for foo.zxurian.com

- First stop is my local DNS (192.168.0.1) -- not found
- Forwards to Route 53. (aws56.awsdns-123.org) -- found, returns 56.45.34.23
- foo.zxurian.com is no pointing to 56.45.34.23 in local dns cache

## Additional Information - Added 2015-01-22 13:02

**Local authoritative server (192.168.0.1) - public IP (100.101.102.103)**

```
          Lookup Zones
         zxurian.local    192.168.0.1
dionysus.zxurian.local    192.168.0.10
    loki.zxurian.local    192.168.0.12

           zxurian.com    23.45.67.89       (public web server)
      test.zxurian.com    192.168.0.50      (internaly hosted web server)
```

**Route 53 Authoritative Server**

```
           zxurian.com    23.45.67.89       (public web server)
      test.zxurian.com    100.101.102.103   (public address of internal web server)
  download.zxurian.com    56.78.95.25       (public web server)
```

So with that information, what I'm trying to ask/accomplish:

A computer outside the local network would always use Route 53, not an issue.
On a computer inside the local network, a request to `download.zxurian.com` would first try the local server (since all local computers use the local server for DNS), but upon failing to find a matching record, it would then look to Route 53.

Would this happen by the local DNS passing the request to route 53, then passing the answer back to the client, or would the client then ask Route 53 directly, or would it happen at all?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any way to do this with Windows DNS.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have the local name server configured as authoritative for a local domain like zxurian.local. or local.zxurian.com. (as well as the 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone for PTR records) and have it do recursive lookups for all other domains.

You'll also benefit from having a local caching server.

There are several how-to documents for BIND9 ([like this one for Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)).  I'm assuming in the Windows universe it is no more difficult.

Comment: Actually the question is about _sub_ domains.

Comment: With the exception of the root domain, all domains are subdomains.  The important thing is that a local service can be configured to be both an authoritative and a recursive service.

Comment: Well, TBH I'll reconsider that. On my side I understood subdomain records for the zxurioan.com zone itself. And that case, I believe your answer would be out of scope. If I misunderstood the question (which is possible), and it was about other domains, then you are on spot.

Comment: added additional information, since I may not have explained it correctly. If using a local caching server, which I would assume caches the dns records of the web itself from it's own dns lookups, would it add the subdomain records to it's own listings, and if thats the case, does it handle conflicts gracefully?

Comment: Whether the local service gets the download.zxurian.com record for the client or refers the client to Route 53's service depends on whether the local service is [configured to be recursive](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00817/0/Nameserver-Basics%3A-What-is-an-Authoritative-Server-What-is-a-Recursive-Server.html).

Comment: The main caveat for your example is that, if you want to have your local service return its own record for test.zxurian.com but let the rest of zxurian.com fall through to Route 53, you need to configure test.zxurian.com as a zone with an A record for the zone origin (a.k.a. "@") instead of trying to serve an A record for "test" in the zxurian.com zone.